# "Out" parameter (reference) with Action<>

Tags: c#, .net

I have many methods similar to this:

```
 void GetColorSky(out float r, out float g, out float b)
 void GetColorGround(out float r, out float g, out float b)
```

"Similar" meaning they have the exact same method header excluding the method name.
I also have several "colourPicker" controls, that accept R, G, B values.

I am trying to create a method that accepts a method as one of it's parameters, like so:

```
UpdateColourPicker(ColorPicker cp, CustomMethod cMethod)
```

and call it as follows:

```
UpdateColourPicker(cpSky, GetColorSky)
UpdateColourPicker(cpGround, GetColorGround)
```

What is the correct syntax for `out` and `Action` together?
I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495636/can-i-have-an-action-or-func-with-an-out-param) but I still haven't managed.

Thanks!

Comment: As a general guideline, it would be better for your functions to return value rather than using out params as they makes functions non-composable

Comment: What is wrong with just declaring those methods like `Color GetColorSky()`? All those out parameters seem quite unnecessary to me.

Comment: @Ankur I have no choice. The functions aren't coming from c# but from an external DLL so I have to use references. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Func<T> with out parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283127/funct-with-out-parameter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking cue from that linked answer, this will work:

```
public delegate void GetColorDel(out float r, out float g, out float b);

void UpdateColourPicker(ColorPicker cp, GetColorDel cMethod) { }

UpdateColourPicker(cpSky, GetColorSky);
UpdateColourPicker(cpGround, GetColorGround);
```

Unfortunately, as stated in the answer to the question you link, `Action` and `Func` do not work with `out` and `ref`. This is simply because `Action` and `Func` are just delegate definitions stated (quite a few times to offer different overloads) with generics in the BCL. Adding `ref` and `out` variants would quickly cause re-definition compiler errors.

The full sample:

```
class Program
{        
    public delegate void GetColorDel(out float r, out float g, out float b);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UpdateColourPicker(null, GetColorSky);
        UpdateColourPicker(null, GetColorGround);

        Console.Read();
    }

    static void GetColorSky(out float r, out float g, out float b) 
    {
        r = g = b = 0f;
        Console.WriteLine("sky"); 
    }

    static void GetColorGround(out float r, out float g, out float b) 
    {
        r = g = b = 0f;
        Console.WriteLine("ground"); 
    }

    static void UpdateColourPicker(object cp, GetColorDel cMethod) 
    {
        float r, g, b;
        cMethod(out r, out g, out b);
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants to know how to use one of the `Action` delegates.

Comment: @leppie: You already told the OP that `out` isn't supported with generic types, so you clearly know that you can't use `out` with `Action<>` delegates. I'm not sure what your comment is getting at.

Comment: @leppie I know, and that is answered in his own linked question. I'll amend to be clearer.

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive answer. I couldn't get the syntax right.

Comment: @David This covers the `float` variant of the method, if you want to use generics then [@jeroenh's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10996698/358221) is the syntax you need. Unforunately generics and arithmetic-styled method don't usually gel very well as standard operators are not supported via generic constraints (`+`, `-`, `*`, etc), so I'd see little benefit in worrying about the generics for now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to define a generic delegate with out parameters, it should be done like this:

```
delegate void ActionWithOutparameter<T>(out T x);
delegate void ActionWithOutparameter<T1, T2>(out T1 x, out T2 y);
// ...
```

Clearly the `Action` and `Func` delegates in the BCL do not match this signature.