# Func delegate with ref variable

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, reference, delegates, func

```
public object MethodName(ref float y)
{
    // elided
}
```

How do I define a `Func` delegate for this method?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

It cannot be done by `Func` but you can define a custom `delegate` for it:

```
public delegate object MethodNameDelegate(ref float y);
```

Usage example:

```
public object MethodWithRefFloat(ref float y)
{
    return null;
}

public void MethodCallThroughDelegate()
{
    MethodNameDelegate myDelegate = MethodWithRefFloat;

    float y = 0;
    myDelegate(ref y);
}
```

Comment: The reason being: all generic type arguments must be things that are convertible to object. "ref float" is not convertible to object, so you cannot use it as a generic type argument.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was struggling to use Func so I know why I cant use it when type is not convertible to object

Comment: Does that mean that the delegate typing will require boxing/unboxing in this case?

Answer (score 10):

In .NET 4+ you can also support `ref` types this way...

```
public delegate bool MyFuncExtension<in string, MyRefType, out Boolean>(string input, ref MyRefType refType);
```

Comment: Not to resurrect a dead thread but it should definitely be noted for anyone that comes across this that while you can support a ref param with generics this way, the generic type parameter will be invariant. Generic type parameters don't support variance (covariance or contravariance) for ref or out parameters in c#. Still fine if you don't need to worry about implicit type conversions though.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is a bit off-track. The `in` and `out` you're showing for paramerizing the delegate pertain to co- versus "contra-variance", and are not related to what the OP is asking about. The question was about delegates which can accept parameters by reference, not the agility of a (generic) delegate with regard to its type parameteriization.