# C# Func(T) not accepting ref type input parameter

Tags: c#-4.0

Can `Func<...>` accept arguments passed by reference in C#?

```
static void Main()
{
    Func<string,int, int> method = Work;
    method.BeginInvoke("test",0, Done, method);
    // ...
    //
}
static int Work(ref string s,int a) { return s.Length; }
static void Done(IAsyncResult cookie)
{
    var target = (Func<string, int>)cookie.AsyncState;
    int result = target.EndInvoke(cookie);
    Console.WriteLine("String length is: " + result);
}
```

I am not able define a `Func<...>` which can accept the `ref` input parameter.

Comment: Why do you think you need a `ref` parameter?

Answer (score 7):

The `Func<T>` delegates cannot take `ref` parameters.
You need to create your own delegate type which takes `ref` parameters.

However, you shouldn't be using `ref` here in the first place.

Comment: For .NET 4 usage...see [this example for using `ref` parameter with `in` and `out` parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24044772/175679).

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on SLaks answers.

The `Func<T>` family of delegates are generic and allow you to customize the type of the arguments and returns.  While `ref` contributes to C#`s type system it's not actually a type at the CLR level: it's a storage location modifier.  Hence it's not possible to use a generic instantiation to control whether or not a particular location is `ref` or not.

If this was possible it would be very easy to produce completely invalid code.  Consider the following

```
T Method<T>() {
  T local = ...;
  ...
  return local;
}
```

Now consider what happens if the developer called `Method<ref int>()`.  It would produce both a local and return value which are `ref`.  This would result in invalid C# code.