# How is a method with out parameters assigned to an ExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, dynamic-language-runtime, expandoobject

I'm trying to assign a method (function) to an ExpandoObject with this signature:

```
public List<string> CreateList(string input1, out bool processingStatus)
{
  //method code...
}
```

I've tried to do something like this code below which doesn't compile:

```
dynamic runtimeListMaker = new ExpandoObject();
runtimeListMaker.CreateList =
     new Func<string, bool, List<string>>(
           (input1, out processingStatus) =>
                {
                     var newList = new List<string>();

                     //processing code...

                     processingStatus = true;
                     return newList;
                });
```

Unfortunately I cannot change the CreateList signature because it will break backward compatibility so rewriting it is not an option. I've tried to get around this by using delegates but at runtime, I got an "Cannot invoke a non-delegate type" exception. I guess this means I'm not assigning the delegate correctly. I need help getting the syntax correct (delegate examples are OK too). Thanks!!

Comment: It is not completely clear what are you trying to get here, but it looks like you're doing something that you don't really need to do. Can you post a code how you would use that `CreateList` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sample compiles and runs as expected:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.Method = new Func<int, string>((i) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        return "Hello World";
    });

obj.Method(10);
Console.ReadKey();
```

The problem with your statement is that your Func does not use an output parameter like your signature does.

```
(input1, out processingStatus)
```

If you want to assign your current method, you won't be able to use Func, but you CAN create your own delegate:

```
    public delegate List<int> MyFunc(int input1, out bool processing);

    protected static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
        obj.Method = new MyFunc(Sample);

        bool val = true;
        obj.Method(10, out val);
        Console.WriteLine(val);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    protected static List<int> Sample(int sample, out bool b)
    {
        b = false;
        return new List<int> { 1, 2 };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code that using `out` parameter type for `processingStatus` parameter which [is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283127/c-func-with-out-parameter/1283143#1283143) in C#.