# Using a out parameter in Func Delegate

Tags: c#-4.0, delegates, func

I have a method signature

```
bool TryGetItem(string itemKey,out Item item)
```

How can i encapsulate this signature in

```
delegate V Func<T,U,V>(T input, out U output)
```

as in the post: [Func<T> with out parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283127/funct-with-out-parameter) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are just written answer.

If you in .net 4.0 or above you can specify variance for parameters.

```
public delegate TV MyFunc<in T, TU, out TV>(T input, out TU output);
```

Then use:

```
bool TryGetItem(string itemKey,out Item item);

MyFunc<string, Item, bool> func = TryGetItem;
```