# How to refactor methods

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

I have two methods. They're very similar.
I've tried use Generics, but it doesn't work with TryParse()

```
    public static int EnterIntengerNumber()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter an intenger number: ");
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int number))
            {
                return number;
            }
            else
            {
                ConsoleError("Incorrect value");
            }
        }
    }


    public static double EnterRealNumber()
    {
        while (true)
        {                
            Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
            if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out double number))
            {
                return number;                    
            }
            else
            {
                ConsoleError("Incorrect value");
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I combine or refactor them?

Comment: They are ok as is, there is no strong need in refactoring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make function, that accepts a delegate with the `TryParse` parameters and return value as generic. Also you can/will have to make string for asking the correct type. but this can be improved from this example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myDouble = EnterSomething<double>("a double", double.TryParse);
        var myInt = EnterSomething<int>("an interger", int.TryParse);
        Console.WriteLine(myDouble);
        Console.WriteLine(myInt);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    public delegate bool TryParseFunction<Tout>(string input, out Tout output);

    public static Tout EnterSomething<Tout>(string typeName, TryParseFunction<Tout> parser)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter " + typeName + " number: ");
            if (parser(Console.ReadLine(), out Tout number))
            {
                return number;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect value");
            }
        }
    }
```

Small additional explanation: the `int.TryParse` - passing to the EnterSomething is not calling the TryParse. It is actually just "passing" the function so that it can be called in the EnterSomething.

The reason of not using `Func<>` is that it does not support out variables, see here some example: [Func<T> with out parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283127/funct-with-out-parameter)

EDIT: I remove the Tin-type parameter, as the input is string anyway.

Comment: I like the ans, specially since this prevents boxing as well as exception (for normal program flow)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Convert.ChangeType`

Do keep in mind you will end up using boxing so the point of using generics is lost. Though you do end up having less code.

```
    public static T EnterNumber<T> ()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter an " + typeof(T) + " number: ");
            try
            {
                return (T) Convert.ChangeType(Console.ReadLine(), typeof(T));
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                Console.Write("Incorrect format" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This message can be improved still:  `Console.Write("Enter an integer number: ")`

Comment: Updated. though I think 'System.Int32' and similar string would not be what the user would be looking for, that could be handled trivially by the OP

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way:

```
public static int EnterIntengerNumber()
{
    return EnterNumber(t => int.TryParse(t, out int v) ? (int?)v : null)
}

public static double EnterRealNumber()
{
    return EnterNumber(t => double.TryParse(t, out double v) ? (double?)v : null)
}

private static T EnterNumber<T>(Func<string, T?> tryParse) where T : struct
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        T? result = tryParse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (result.HasValue)
        {
            return result.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            ConsoleError("Incorrect value");
        }
    }
}
```