# Is it possible to assign a method with out parameter to a Func<X> in parameter

Tags: c#, func, out

Would it be possible to assign a method with `out` parameters to a `Func<T1, T2>` method parameter?

An example method I could use as parameter:

```
public string HelloMethod(out bool success)
{
    success = true;
    return "Hello";
};
```

The reason I want to do this is that I call a library where many (but not all) methods have `out` parameters with error codes and I want create a method to wrap the calls to the library with `try catch log` etc:

```
private TResult MakeLibraryCall(...func...) // what signature?
{
    try
    {
        return func(...); // unclear how to make call with out parameter
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        Log(error);
    }

    return default;
}
```

Further I'm not sure how this would be called.
I hope for something like:

```
var greeting = MakeLibraryCall((out success) => HelloMetod(out success));

Console.WriteLine(greeting) // => Hello
Console.WriteLine(success) // => true
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Func<T> with out parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283127/funct-with-out-parameter)

Comment: @AhmedYousif: not sure how I would implement that delegate pattern in my code? It might work, but I don't know how to write the solution.

Comment: you can check my answer it enough to achieve what you want to do

Answer (score 2):

According to [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0) Built-in Delegate Func<T,TResult> its input parameter is not defined as out parameter

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T,out TResult>(T arg);
```

So you should define your custom delegate as follows:

```
delegate T MyDelegate<T,TInput>(out TInput input);
```

Then make it a prameter to your MakeLibraryCall function as follows:

```
private string MakeLibraryCall(MyDelegate<string,bool> func) 
{
    try
    {
        bool x = true;
        return func(out x); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Log(error);
    }

    return default;
}
```

after that call the function  MakeLibraryCall as follows:

```
public string HelloMethod(out bool success)
{
    success = true;
    return "Hello";
};

var greeting = MakeLibraryCall(HelloMethod);
```

if you want to out the parameter of **func** from MakeLibraryCall so you have to define it as out parameter of it as follows:

```
private string MakeLibraryCall(MyDelegate<string,bool> func, out bool success) 
    {
        try
        {
            return func(out success);  
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Log(error);
            success = false;
        }
    
        return default;
    }

var success = false;
var greeting = MakeLibraryCall(HelloMethod,out success);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at it, but I won't be at work until Thursday